# Characterization of proper maps

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a map between topological spaces.

$f$ is proper if compactness is invariant under preimage; this implies that it maps closed and discrete sets into discrete sets. Is this last property also sufficient for properness?

Comment: I'm having some trouble parsing the question. By `Is this last property also sufficient for properness?', do you mean "Is it true that if $f(X)$ is discrete whenever $X$ is closed or (and?) discrete, then $f$ is proper"?

Comment: The constant map from an infinite discrete space to a space with one point maps anything to a closed discrete set, but it's obviously not proper

Comment: @BrandonduPreez: yes. Properness implies $f(X)$ discrete whenever $X$ is closed and discrete. I was wondering if, when this holds, then $f$ is necessarely proper.

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary spaces such that $X$ is not compact and $Y$ is $T_1$, then any constant map $X\to Y$ maps anything to a discrete closed set, but it's clearly not proper.

Comment: Short: the map $x\in \mathbb R\mapsto 0\in\mathbb R$ maps to a discrete closed set and it is not proper. Nice observation.

Comment: Thanks. What about non constant maps? When does hold the implication I'm wondering about?